# Copy settings and preferences to new mac

Tags: macos, preferences

I have a Mac at the office and will be buying a new one for home. Is there a way to move my preferences and settings from the old computer to the new one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply copy the contents of your ~/Library from your old user account to your new user account on your new machine.

Comment: Would there be any permissions issues with doing it this way?

Comment: @dwightk There shouldn't be, but as with everything you should always do an ACL reset after it.

Comment: If I copy the library over and then install an application, will it write a new preferences file over my old one, or work off the old one?

Comment: @aszekely It'll use the old one

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can use the Migration Assistant software that's included in all recent versions of OS X. See [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5872) for Apple's instructions on using it in Mavericks. You'll need to be able to connect your old Mac to your new one, over a local area network (either wired or wireless) or using a Thunderbolt or Firewire cable

Comment: Will it copy over all the broken stuff? IE, for the life of me I can't get the copy screen shot selection to work anymore in chrome or some other apps